# How to add a shortcode in a button (Woo/WP)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added Cart recovered plugin and in the template of my email I want to add a button (Go to my cart), with the shortcode linking the cart : {rac.cartlink}

How can I add this shortcode in a button. I just want to design and emphasis this code.

I am using this html mode (with css), but it doesn't work :

```
<p style="text-align: center;"><a class="BTN" href="XXX">XXX</a></p>
```

I am using WP/Woocommerce.

Thank you

Comment: can you plz add the code you have tried.

Comment: <p style="text-align: center;"><a class="BTN" href="XXX">XXX</a></p>